# How to get window.checkoutConfig value in html file using data-bind

Tags: magento2, javascript, html, system-config, data-bind

I made my custom delivery method programmatically. It also appears in the Magento 2 admin config section. It is a multi-select field with values of days of the week. In my js file below:

```
define(
    [
        'ko',
        'uiComponent',
        'underscore',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
        'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer'
    ],
    function (
        ko,
        Component,
        _,
        stepNavigator,
        customer
    ) {
        'use strict';
        /**
         * check-login - is the name of the component's .html template
         */
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'A4_CustomDelivery/check-login'
            },

            //add here your logic to display step,
            isVisible: ko.observable(true),
            isLogedIn: customer.isLoggedIn(),
            //step code will be used as step content id in the component template
            stepCode: 'isLogedCheck',
            //step title value
            stepTitle: 'Delivery Date & Time',

            /**
             *
             * @returns {*}
             */
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
                // register your step
                stepNavigator.registerStep(
                    this.stepCode,
                    //step alias
                    null,
                    this.stepTitle,
                    //observable property with logic when display step or hide step
                    this.isVisible,

                    _.bind(this.navigate, this),

                    /**
                     * sort order value
                     * 'sort order value' < 10: step displays before shipping step;
                     * 10 < 'sort order value' < 20 : step displays between shipping and payment step
                     * 'sort order value' > 20 : step displays after payment step
                     */
                    15
                );

                return this;
            },

            /**
             * The navigate() method is responsible for navigation between the checkout step
             * during checkout. You can add custom logic, for example, some conditions
             * for switching to your custom step
             */
            navigate: function () {

            },

            /**
             * @returns void
             */
            navigateToNextStep: function () {
                var customDate = window.checkoutConfig.a4date;
                var customTime = window.checkoutConfig.a4time;

                console.log(customDate);
                console.log(customTime);
                
                stepNavigator.next();
            }
        });
    }
);
```

When I use console.log to check its value, it returns those selected items successfully but I want to use its value in the **option tag** in an HTML file below:

```
<!--Use 'stepCode' as id attribute-->
<li data-bind="fadeVisible: isVisible, attr: { id: stepCode }">
    <div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: stepTitle" data-role="title"></div>
    <div id="checkout-step-title"
         class="step-content"
         data-role="content">
        <p>The customer is <span data-bind="if: !isLogedIn">not</span> Logged-in</p>


        <form data-bind="submit: navigateToNextStep" novalidate="novalidate">
            <label for="deliverydate">Delivery Date:</label>
            <input type="date"
                   id="deliverydate"
                   name="deliverydate"
                   min="2022-08-10"
                   max="2050-08-31">
            <label for="appt">Select a time:</label>
            <input type="time" id="appt" name="appt">
            
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <div class="primary">
                    <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
                        <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Next'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</li>
```

I want to make a **select HTML field** with **option values** obtained from ***window.checkoutConfig.a4date*** in this file. These are the values

> Array(3) [ "Tuesday", "Friday", "Saturday" ]
> checkout-login-step.js:80:25

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these 2 lines in html file.

```
<select data-bind="event:{ change: getDate}, options: availableDates, selectedOptions: chosenDate"></select>
<select data-bind="event:{ change: getTime}, options: availableTimes, selectedOptions: chosenTime"></select>
```

and get values from the function `window.checkoutConfig.<YOUR_VALUE>` as follows:

```
let date = window.checkoutConfig.a4date;
    let dateValues = date.toString().split(",");
    if (dateValues[0] === '') {
        dateValues = [];
        dateValues.push('Tuesday');
}

let time = window.checkoutConfig.a4time;
    let timeValues = time.toString().split(",");
    if (timeValues[0] === '') {
        timeValues = [];
        timeValues.push('13:00-16:00');
    }
```

Finally, use these values in the functions created.

```
chosenDate : ko.observableArray([dateValues[0]]),
    availableDates : ko.observableArray(
        (dateValues)
    ),
    getDate:function (data, event) {
       //console.log(this.chosenDate());
    },

chosenTime : ko.observableArray([timeValues[0]]),
    availableTimes : ko.observableArray(
        (timeValues)
    ),
    getTime:function (data, event) {
       //console.log(this.chosenTime());
    }
```