# how to pass js window varibles from templates to template files in magento? I want to get system config values in the web folder

Tags: javascript, template, phtml, html, system.xml

I want to pass js window variables from **view/frontend/templates/form.phtml** to **view /web/template/shipping-information.html** and **view/web/js/shipping-information.js**
How can I do it?

it is because I want to get system.xml file values in that **web** folder.
I am able to get it in the phtml files using helper but stuck here.

can any one help?

Comment: You can check [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/358811/108564), maybe you are facing the same issue. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I did write a public repository a while ago: `https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/productcompare/src/master/`

In this repository, I use the uicomponent technology that is widely used in Magento. But particularly, I use a file called `state` and this file contains the data that my module handles. And each uicomponent pulls the data using the state as a dependency.

Of course, uicomponent is complex and you may want to use something simpler but if you are already comfortable with them, then this state file is possibly something that will answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

I found out that we can get the values using window variables
use the following in phtml files to js files.
**view/frontend/templates/sample.phtml**

```
<?php $helper= $this->helper('Vendor\Module\Helper\Data') ?>
  <script>
       window.variable_name = '<?php echo $helper->getMethod("configId"); ?>';
  </script>
```

after that use call the window.variable in html file
**view/frontend/web/js/sample.js**

```
alert('config value from window variable from phtml file is ',window.variable_name);
```

In some way this one solved my problem.